# docker with postgres and bash

Tags: postgresql, docker

Today I was researching and trying docker, and with the most of things I was impressed. There are still some questions for me about docker.

Can anyone more experienced than me with Docker tell me what is the best way to login to postgres container (run bash), in order to view some postgres configuration files, view postgres logs, log into postgres shell, execute pg_dump for example, etc. etc..., and everything this while postgres process is running.

I see that people usually run one process per container, and with this approach I am not sure what is the best way to do mentioned actions on container which runs postgres?

Any advices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can usually get a shell like this:

```
docker exec -it some-node bash
```

Answer (score 1):

The canonical docker way would be not to log in to the running db container, but instead do `docker logs` or link other containers to do maintenance tasks (e.g. `docker run -it --rm --link <my-pg-container>:pg <my-pg-image> pgsql --host pg` etc..